# Ensure local PHP execution

Tags: php, local

I'm looking for a secure solution to ensure that my PHP script is executing LOCALLY via shell (not via 127.0.0.1)

e.g.

```
C:\php > php P:\ath\to\script.php
```

The reason : cron or win task scheduler will run this script once per month to generate a token that grants access to another page (MySQL stuff) and I don't want external clients to be able to run this script.

Comment: What difference does it make? `127.0.0.1` is also local

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer: **do not put something, that should not be accessed by web, to web-accessible place**

However, if you want to check that, you can check `argv` key of `$_SERVER` array. If it exists, then it is CLI call (and `[0]` element of this array will hold script's name). I.e.

```
if(array_key_exists('argv', $_SERVER))
{
   //cli call
}
else
{
   //non-cli call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the script in a dir not accessible from web.
If that is not a possibility create a .htaccess file that deny access from all. That way you can reach it from the machine, but not from the web.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```